# google spreadsheets query sql in operator

Tags: google-sheets

First I will explain what I am trying to achieve

I have a list with several columns and rows, like this

```
  | a  |  b |  c
-----------------
1 | f1 |  4 |  f
2 | f2 |  9 |  k
3 | f3 |  1 |  x
```

In another column outside the list I want to write a list with variable size, that contains values of column 'a'.

This list would be for a query like this (suppose that I write the variable list in the column 'd')

```
=QUERY(A2:D3,"SELECT a, b, c WHERE A IN D")
```

I think the problem is that I can not use the IN operator from sql

Is there a way to achieve this? The most important part is that I want to write manually a list with variable size for the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thy this formula, in cell E1:

`=FILTER(A:C,REGEXMATCH(A:A,JOIN("|",FILTER(D:D,D:D<>""))))`

---

[`FILTER`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) formula can take any array as condition parameter.  [`REGEXMATCH`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098292?hl=en) + [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) with pipe `|` will match `true` when any text from `D` matches text from `A`.

---

This formula is good for one more reason, you may use it as source for further query, like this: `=query(my_formula, "select Col1, Col3 where Col2 > 0")`